# Dart - Problems reading body from a HttpRequest on a server after getting a POST

Tags: rest, dart, server

I am trying to get the body of a POST request. In Postman I am sending a json. The header is defined as application/json. What I am expecting from this simple piece of code is a string representation of the json data. The contents of 'content' in my example here is empty (I print it to console). What am I not understanding here? Any help here would be greatly appreciated :)

```
main() async {
  var server = await HttpServer.bind("0.0.0.0", 8080);
  print("Serving at ${server.address}:${server.port}");

  await for (HttpRequest request in server) {
    String content = await utf8.decoder.bind(request).join();
    print("CONTENT:" + content);
  }
}
```

Comment: Works fine here when using Postman to send a POST request. How are you testing the code? You should also properly add `await request.response.close();` after `print` so the client sending the message are not waiting forever for an answer.

Comment: Takk julemand. I am testing this code by running an Ubuntu server in VMWare that runs docker. I have two containers; nginx and dart. I run Postman on my local machine. Everything I've done up to this point has worked fine (serving html, files, stream video with partial content support etc) so I'm a bit stumped. I'm quite new to the language so there must be something I am not understanding correctly.

Comment: Update: Seems the code works. Tried running it using SDK on Windows and I got the output. I was originally testing on a different setup; Ubuntu server in VMWare Player running nginx & dart containers in docker. I must examine my environment to find out where this goes wrong.